# useRef() returning 'undefined' when used with custom hook on initial render when using filter()

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have an image slider component and a simple custom hook that gets the refElement and the width of the element using the useRef hook. -

The code sandbox is here [Image Slider](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sound-xqglgk)

When I use the slider component and just map the data in without filtering, everything works fine. If I filter and map the data then I get `Uncaught TypeError: elementRef.current is undefined` . (In the sandbox you have to comment out the second instance (unfiltered) of SliderTwo to recreate the error. Why does it work without the filter but not with (when rendered by itself)? More in depth explanation below.

useSizeElement()

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useSizeElement = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const elementRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(elementRef.current.clientWidth); // This will give us the width of the element
  }, [elementRef.current]);

  return { width, elementRef };
};

export default useSizeElement;
```

I call the hook (useSizeElement) inside of a context because I need the width to use in another hook in a different component thus:

context

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import useSizeElement from '../components/flix-slider/useSizeElement';

export const SliderContext = createContext();

  export const SliderProvider = ({children}) => {
    const { width, elementRef } = useSizeElement();
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState();
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    console.log('context - width', width, 'elementRef', elementRef)
   
  
    const showDetailsHandler = movie => {
      setCurrentSlide(movie);
      setIsOpen(true)
    };
  
    const closeDetailsHandler = () => {
      setCurrentSlide(null);
      setIsOpen(false)
    };
  
    const value = {
      onShowDetails: showDetailsHandler,
      onHideDetails: closeDetailsHandler,
      elementRef,
      currentSlide,
      width,
      isOpen
    };  

      return <SliderContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SliderContext.Provider>

  }
```

I get the width of the  component from the elementRef that was passed from the context.-
Item Component

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import { SliderContext } from '../../store/SliderContext.context';
import ShowDetailsButton from './ShowDetailsButton';
import Mark from './Mark';
import { ItemContainer } from './item.styles';

const Item = ({ show }) => {
  const { onShowDetails, currentSlide, isOpen, elementRef } =
    useContext(SliderContext);

  const isActive = currentSlide && currentSlide.id === show.id;  

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ItemContainer
        className={isOpen ? 'open' : null}
        ref={elementRef}
        isActive={isActive}
        isOpen={isOpen}
      >
        <img
          src={show.thumbnail.regular.medium}
          alt={`Show title: ${show.title}`}
        />
        <ShowDetailsButton onClick={() => onShowDetails(show)} />
      </ItemContainer>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

The width is passed using context where another hook is called in the Slider Component:

Slide Component

```
import useSizeElement from './useSizeElement';
import { OuterContainer } from './SliderTwo.styles';


const SliderTwo = ({ children }) => {
  const {currentSlide, onHideDetails, isOpen, width, elementRef } = useContext(SliderContext);
  
  
  const { handlePrev, handleNext, slideProps, containerRef, hasNext, hasPrev } =
    useSliding( width, React.Children.count(children));


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SliderWrapper>
        <OuterContainer isOpen={isOpen}>
          <div ref={containerRef} {...slideProps}>
            {children}
          </div>
        </OuterContainer>
        {hasPrev && <SlideButton showLeft={hasPrev} onClick={handlePrev} type="prev" />}
        {hasNext && <SlideButton showRight={hasNext} onClick={handleNext} type="next" />}
      </SliderWrapper>
      {currentSlide && <Content show={currentSlide} onClose={onHideDetails} />}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default SliderTwo;
```

Now everything works fine if I just map the data with **no filters** into the slider as shown in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sound-xqglgk). But if I apply a filter to display only what I want I get -
`Uncaught TypeError: elementRef.current is undefined`
I do know that you can't create a ref on an element that does not yet exist and I've seen examples where you can use useEffect to get around it but I can't find the solution to get it to work.
Here is the App.js - To see the error I'm getting, comment out the second instance of . As long as I'm running one instance without filtering the data, it works, but it won't work by itself.

```
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import SliderTwo from "./components/SliderTwo";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import shows from "./data.json";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const datafunc = () => {
    let filteredData = shows.filter((show) => {
      if (show.isTrending === true) {
        return show;
      }
    });
    setData(filteredData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    datafunc();
  }, []);

  console.log("Trending movies", data);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="testDiv">
        {shows && data && (
          <SliderTwo>
            {data && data.map((show) => <Item show={show} key={show.id} />)}
          </SliderTwo>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="testDiv">
        <SliderTwo>
          {shows.map((show) => (
            <Item show={show} key={show.id} />
          ))}
        </SliderTwo>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Full code: Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sound-xqglgk

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be an issue when the useSizeElement is first mounted as the useEffect will run once at the beginning of each render.
When it runs at the first instance and the ref is not yet defined so it was returning the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')

If you modify your code to this I believe it should work:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const useSizeElement = () => {
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
const elementRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   if (elementRef.current) setWidth(elementRef.current.clientWidth); // 
   This will give us the width of the element
}, [elementRef]);

   return { width, elementRef };
};

export default useSizeElement;
```

This way you are checking if the elementRef is defined first before setting the width

UPDATE:

```
 <Fragment>
  <div className="testDiv">
    <SliderTwo>
      {shows
        .filter((show) => {
          if (show.isTrending === true) {
            return show;
          }
          return false;
        })
        .map((show) => (
          <Item show={show} key={show.id} />
        ))}
    </SliderTwo>
  </div>
  {/* <div className="testDiv">
    <SliderTwo>
      {shows.map((show) => (
        <Item show={show} key={show.id} />
      ))}
    </SliderTwo>
  </div> */}
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Well that got the initial render of the filtered data to work but it breaks the useSliding hook somehow and the slide buttons dont render to get the slider to work. If you look at the console logs when using the non-flitered component, the first render is undefined and then it re-renders and you see the width and element. I can't figure out why it doesn't throw an error there but does with the filtered data.

Comment: Hey @Peshwari_Naan, I don't know if you solved it yet. But i did a bit of testing and moved the filter logic into the component and it seems to work now. I don't know why as I'm a bit confused as well. I've editied my current answer at the bottom. Let me know if it helps you. Also as an additional note in filter, although not needed, it is good to return false when you don't want the element as well

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I think when the filter method was being run outside that the call to the hook is happening before the component has been created. I tried a few things to get it to re-render after the initial render but nothing I did worked. I really appreciate the help.